# Print JSON keys of an array within another array in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have the following **JSON** code:

```
{
   "google.com": {
        "clicks": 23,
        "browsers": {
            "Chrome": 19,
            "Mozilla": 2,
            "Safari": 1
        }
    },
    "mcnitro.net": {
        "clicks": 87,
        "browsers": {
            "Chrome": 19,
            "Mozilla": 2,
            "Safari": 1
        }
    }
}
```

And I am endeavouring to print on the document page the arrays' names and their children.
So far, I have tried the following **PHP** code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    $jsonString = file_get_contents('stats.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    foreach($data->children() as $domain) {
        echo $data[$domain];
        foreach($data[$domain] as $value) {
            echo $value['clicks'];
        }
    }
?>
```

However, I am facing an issue in the `error_log`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on array in /home/gamin167/public_html/ads/engine/300x250/gen.js.php on line 5
```

The result wanted was to have "google.com" and "mcnitro.net" printed, as well as their "clicks" property.

Any tip or advice will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes you think $data was an object that had a `children` method …?

Comment: `$data` will be an associative array, that which doesn't have a function named `children()`. `foreach($data->children() as $domain) {` should be replaced with `foreach($data as $k=>$doman){`..

Comment: No idea, to be impartial. I am rather fresh to PHP and have discovered that composition of code on the Internet.

Comment: `children()` looks more like an XML method, which is just another data file format.

Answer (score 0):

You decode the string to an array with `true` yet you seem to try and use it as an object.
Also there is no need to loop twice.

```
foreach($data as $key => $domain) {
    echo $key . "\n";
    echo $domain['clicks'] . "\n\n";

}
```

output:

```
google.com
23

mcnitro.net
87
```

https://3v4l.org/D7FCY

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `->children()`. `$data` is an array with your json data, and you can use `foreach` to get `key` and `value`, like `foreach ($data as $key => $value)`.

So here, to get your domain name, just do :

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    $jsonString = file_get_contents('stats.json');
    $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    foreach($data as $domain => $value) {
        echo $value['clicks'];
    }
?>
```